# How to get a controller variable in a URLFOR

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlfor

@import url({!URLFOR($Resource.brand, '{!cssName}')});

Is it possible to call an apex variable in the path section of a URLFOR if the styling varies in some cases? In the above code in the visualforce page the variable doe not get populated. The controller is definitely being used. Or is there an alternative to URLFOR where this could work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already "escaped", you don't need to escape again. Assuming the variable is called cssName:

```
@import url({!URLFOR($Resource.brand, cssName)});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it worked! You're amazing

Answer (score 0):

How if I want to have a controller variable in URLFOR like below.
'practiceId' in the below code is my variable in controller.

```
 <apex:commandButton value="New Notes" action="{!URLFOR('002/parent_id='+{!practiceId},null,[retURL=URLFOR('%2F'+{!practiceId})])}"/>
```